# ROS path relocation error

Tags: roslaunch, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I recently moved my main `ros` directory and now I cannot start executables like `roslaunch`, `rosmake`, or `rosdep`. I had made sure to edit my `setup.sh` file so I'm very confused about what's gone wrong. Details:

When I first installed Diamondback, `roscd` would take me to `/opt/ros/diamondback/ros`. Everything worked fine, but I foudn it just a bit annoying so I moved the whole `diamondback` directory to `/home/khiya/` and changed the environment variables in `setup.sh` (located in the `diamondback` directory) accordingly. `roscd` now takes me straight to `/home/khiya/diamondback/ros`, but when I tried running any executables, such as `roslaunch` (kinda crucial, I know) I got this error:

```
     :~/diamondback/ros$ roscore
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/home/khiya/diamondback/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>
            from ros import roslaunch
          File "/home/khiya/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
            raise ImportError("Cannot import module '%s': \n%s"%(name, str(e)))
        ImportError: Cannot import module 'roslaunch': 
        Cannot locate installation of package roslaunch: 
    /home/khiya/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack: error while loading shared libraries: 
librospack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. 
ROS_ROOT[/home/khiya/diamondback/ros] 
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/khiya/sandbox/hrl_rfid:/home/khiya/ros_tutorials:
/home/khiya/diamondback/stacks]
```

(The last 5 lines are one continuous line, I just chopped it up for easier reading, in case that's important). The error seems to be saying that the directory `/home/khiya/diamondback/ros/bin` doesn't contain any of those important executables, but I can `cd` there and see that they're there. Do I need to tweak something in `librospack.so`?

Thanks very much,

Khiya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10381/ros-path-relocation-error/) by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, it is a really bad idea to just rename/move ROS packages without recompiling them. To me it seems that you installed ROS from debian packages and then just moved the whole installation which basically will interfere with your package manager. People normally don't do that :)

The reason why you are running into problems is RPATH. It's a property that can be set for linux libraries and binaries and it specifies the absolute path to libraries used by that binary. If you now move the whole tree, these paths will be wrong and binaries will be unable to find the required libraries.

Instead of moving the whole tree you can do a source-based installation in your home, but I wouldn't recommend that. Instead you normally make an overlay in your home. You can find some interesting information about that [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/181/how-exactly-does-rosinstall-work) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2